# Neo4j : iterate through relationship

Tags: neo4j, sum

I'm using Neo4j 3.0.6 and I want to do something like that :

```
for k in keys(r):
    if k >= `2015-01`:
       sum(values(k)) as sum
```

I tried foreach but it doesn't work.
In the model, the key of my relationship is a pair of date and a criterion. Here is an example:

```
<id>... 2015-01,c:500 2015-02,c:23 2015-03,c:900 2015-01,r:56
```

The expected resulat :

```
sum 
923
```

So, I'm looking to get the sum of the criterion c when it's greater than `2015-01`
Thank you

Comment: can you clarify what you're asking about? your pseudocode and graph sample are not very comprehensible. What is the structure of your data, what are you iterating over, what do you want to get as a result of the iteration?

Comment: I modified my example. Please see the post above and I hope it's clear
Thank you

Comment: So a single relationship will have a Map of date/count pairs, and you want to find that relationship and get the sum of the counts for dates gte `2015-01`?

Comment: I have a single relationship between each pair of nodes and it has a Map of date/criterion pairs. So, at the end `2015-01` exists for both criteria {c,r} and I want to get the sum for one of these criterion let's assume c for dates greater than `2015-01`

Comment: are all of these nodes in a single path, or do you have multiple separate node pairs that you want to sum up? what's your cypher query for `MATCH`ing these nodes and their relationships?

Comment: Something like this:
`MATCH (origin:AirportFR),
      (destination:AirportFR),
      (origin)-[r]-(destination)
WHERE origin.code IN ['JFK', 'ATX'] and destination.code IN ['BUY', 'PUQ']
RETURN origin,  destination,r`

Comment: I tried to do a dynamic lookup so it answered to my question and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

```
MATCH (origin:AirportFR)
WHERE origin.code IN ['JFK', 'ATX']
MATCH (destination:AirportFR)
WHERE destination.code IN ['BUY', 'PUQ']
MATCH (origin) - [r] - (destination)
UNWIND [k IN KEYS(r) WHERE split(k, ',')[0] >= '2015-01' AND split(k, ',')[1] = 'c'| r[k] ] AS c_values
RETURN SUM(c_values)
```

`SUM` is an aggregation function that expects to collect data from several rows, so you have to get the property you want into rows. To generate these rows, you're going to have to `UNWIND` a filtered list of the keys for each row. But as mentioned below, seriously consider changing your data model so that you don't have to run string analysis on your keys.

Comment: But I can't do this : `WHERE r >= '2015-01'`  with my actual model since my relationship is like that :
`<id>... 2015-01,c:500 2015-02,c:23 2015-03,c:900 2015-01,r:56`

Comment: where did you get that notation? can you explain it using Cypher or regular map notation?

Comment: An other thing that it isn't possible: `SUM(r.c)` because the property is like that: `2015-01,c` So, I need to do a condition to see if my criteria c exists in the property name and to compare this on with `2015-01` and then check this condition for the others keys or properties name before doing the sum

Comment: I do it by using pyn2eo to create my graph. Rather than create relationship by  date. I created only one and group all date with criteria.

Comment: that is a really awkward way to model your data. you'd have a much easier time if you made a relationship *per date*, and use regular key:value pairs to model your 'c' or 'r' attribute and the corresponding value. That said, the query above will do what you want now. But seriously consider changing your model, key parsing isn't well supported in any language anywhere.

Comment: here is the cypher query to create this: 
`CREATE (origin:AirportFR {code: "AAA"})-[:`TO` {`2015-01,c`:500,`2015-02,c`:23,`2015-03,c`:900,`2015-01,r`:56}]->(destination:AirportFR{code: "BOD"})`

Comment: `MERGE (origin:AirportFR {code: "AAA"}) MERGE (d‌​est:AirportFR‌​{code: "BOD"}) MERGE (origin) - [:TO {date:'2015-01', c: 500, r: 56}] -> (dest) MERGE (origin) - [:TO {date: '2015-02', c: 24}] -> (dest) MERGE (origin) - [:TO {date:'2015-03', c: 900}]-> (dest)` will result in a way more query-able structure.

Comment: I don't want to use this model because it generates a large graph. It's for this reason, I opt to group all information in single relation

Comment: Graphs are good at storing a large number of nodes and relationships. They are very bad at storing and querying large numbers of properties. You are working against your tools here, which is why your query is always going to look tortured and perform badly.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. You are right, it's better to use relationships per date rather than a single with many properties